# SQLite Ranking Time Stamps

Tags: sqlite

I am new to SQL and am having trouble with a (fairly simple) query to rank time stamps.

I have one table with survey data from 2014. I am trying to determine the 'learning curve' for good customer satisfaction performance. I want to order and rank each survey at an agent level based on the time stamp of the survey. This would let me see what the average performance is when an agent has 5 total surveys, 10, 20 etc.

I imagine it should be something like (table name is tablerank):

```
select  T1.*,
       (select  count(*) 
        from    tablerank as T2
        where   T2.call_date > T1.call_date
        ) as SurveyRank
from    tablerank as T1
where   p1.Agent_ID = T2.Agent_ID;
```

For each agent, it would list each survey in order and tag a 1 for the earliest survey, a 2 for the second earliest, etc. Then I could Pivot the data in Excel and see the learning curve based on survey count rather than tenure or time (since surveys are more rare, sometimes you only get 1 or 2 in a month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correlated subquery must have the correlation in the subquery itself; any table names/aliases from the subquery (such as `T2`) are not visible in the outer query.

For ranking, you want to count *earlier* surveys, and you want to include the *current* survey so that the first one gets the rank number `1`, so you need to use `<=` instead of `>`:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tablerank AS T2
        WHERE T2.Agent_ID = T1.Agent_ID
          AND T2.call_date <= T1.call_date
       ) AS SurveyRank
FROM tablerank AS T1
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Man, I envy that you were able to look at it and resolve it so quickly. I spent hours playing with that. Sigh.